# Xamarin iOS Google Sign-in component : App crashes due to error uiDelegate must either be a |UIViewController| or implement

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, google-signin

I'm trying to implement google sign in using this component for xamarin.ios: [Google Sign-in for iOS](https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleiossignin)

It works great on emulator but when it comes to actual device it's crashing once i tap signin button. (iOS 10.2 - emulator is also using same OS)
I have a custom button which calls SignInUser method on SignIn.SharedInstance

It's crashing with below error (only when the app is deployed on device)

*Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: uiDelegate must either be a |UIViewController| or implement the |signIn:presentViewController:| and |signIn:dismissViewController:| methods from |GIDSignInUIDelegate|.*

I'm calling function below to initialize GoogleSignIn on FinishedLaunching method of AppDelegate.cs

```
public void Configure()
    {
        NSError configureError;
        Context.SharedInstance.Configure(out configureError);

        if (configureError != null)
        {
            // If something went wrong, assign the clientID manually
            Console.WriteLine("Error configuring the Google context: {0}", configureError);
            SignIn.SharedInstance.ClientID = googleClientId;
        }

        SignIn.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;
        SignIn.SharedInstance.UIDelegate = new GoogleSignInUIDelegate();
    }
```

Here's my implementation of ISignInUIDelegate():

```
class GoogleSignInUIDelegate :  SignInUIDelegate
{
    public override void WillDispatch(SignIn signIn, NSError error)
    {
    }
    public override void PresentViewController(SignIn signIn, UIViewController viewController)
    {
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(viewController, true, null);

    }

    public override void DismissViewController(SignIn signIn, UIViewController viewController)
    {
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.DismissViewController(true, null);
    }
}
```

So the emulator seems to know the methods are implemented, but not the device. Any idea what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging i found where the actual issue was. 
Somehow, the UIDelegate i assigned during initialization was lost when i was calling my login method. So i moved the line below from my initialization step to login

`SignIn.SharedInstance.UIDelegate = new GoogleSignInUIDelegate();`

Here's how my login method looks like now:

```
    public void Login()
    {
        SignIn.SharedInstance.UIDelegate = new GoogleSignInUIDelegate(); //moved this here from Configure
        SignIn.SharedInstance.SignInUser();
    }
```

This took care of the issue for me but i am still not sure why this is only an issue on the device and not the emulator. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `PreserveAttribute` to your `GoogleSignInUIDelegate` class to prevent the Linker from removing the methods that can not be determined via static analysis.

#### Add the following class to your project:

```
public sealed class PreserveAttribute : System.Attribute {
    public bool AllMembers;
    public bool Conditional;
}
```

#### Apply the class attribute:

```
[Preserve (AllMembers = true)] 
class GoogleSignInUIDelegate :  SignInUIDelegate
{
  ~~~~
}
```

Re: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/

Comment: Thanks much, i tried this but it didn't solve the issue. I found that the linker behavior is set to _Link SDK Assemblies Only_ so may be it wasn't removing methods from my assembly, however I've put this in to make sure it won't be removed by linker in future. I've found my issue to be something different, i will post the answer below.

Comment: @SanjogSharma Glad you found it... If you enable `Link All` to minimize your final `.ipa` size you will most likely need to use the `PreserveAttribute`... Interested now what your problem actually was...

Comment: i posted the answer now

Answer (score 0):

Setting PresentingViewController helped me to resolve the issue.

```
SignIn.SharedInstance.PresentingViewController = this;
```

Have found such fix here:
https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity/issues/169#issuecomment-791305225